# Apply Custom Classes / Functions on Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a class `DataImporter` with a method called `getData` that I want to apply on a pandas dataframe. The problem: the class / method can just handle single elements.

Imagine I have a DataFrame with three columns `id`, `a` and `b`.

What I actually want to do is something like: (pseudo code)

`df["c"] = Class(df["id"]).getData(df["a"], df["b"])`

I found out there is something like pandas.Series.apply, but I don't see that it works for the `getData` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process data by scalars in columns:

```
df["c"] = df.apply(lambda x: Class(x["id"]).getData(x["a"], x["b"]), axis=1)
```